# Regular Expressions in Oracle 9i

Tags: oracle

Hi Can any body please help me out , My scenario is

```
select to_number(((replace('1*Students', 'Students','60')))) 
  from dual;
```

If I used like this , Invalid Number error is coming.
How to convert to number and it should display the result as "60", Please help me out, I stacked. Thanks a ton in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
select
 to_number( substr ( replace('1*Students', 'Students','60'), 0,instr( replace('1*Students', 'Students','60'), '*' )-1 ),'9999.99')    

 *
 to_number(substr ( replace('1*Students', 'Students','60'), instr(  replace('1*Students', 'Students','60'), '*' )+1 ),'9999.99')

from dual
```

[fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/3769)